# How to distinguish points below and above geolocalised polyline?

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas

I've got two geodataframes - one with polylines and second one containing points; up until now I was working with single polyline and couple of points that look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cm4A.png). I am trying to achieve an outcome somehow similiar to the one decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574595/how-to-pick-points-under-the-curve).

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt

roadpd = pd.read_csv('roads.csv',delimiter=';')

roadpd['geom'] = roadpd['geom'].apply(wkt.loads)
roadgpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(roadpd, geometry=roadpd['geom'])
print(roadgpd)

addresspd = pd.read_csv('addresses.csv',delimiter=';')

addresspd['geom'] = addresspd['geom'].apply(wkt.loads)
addressgpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(addresspd, geometry=addresspd['geom'])
print(addressgpd)

   ROA_ID                                               geom                                           geometry
0      23  LINESTRING (16.8978861 52.417438, 16.8971243 5...  LINESTRING (16.89789 52.41744, 16.89712 52.417...
     ADG_ID                                         geom                   geometry
0   6641801   POINT (16.89397537268492 52.4186416491154)  POINT (16.89398 52.41864)
1   6641802  POINT (16.89458531052842 52.41814952579504)  POINT (16.89459 52.41815)
2   6641803  POINT (16.89499192732443 52.41803648483478)  POINT (16.89499 52.41804)
3   6641804  POINT (16.89532584370729 52.41794434305021)  POINT (16.89533 52.41794)
4   6641805  POINT (16.89553809175901 52.41786913837524)  POINT (16.89554 52.41787)
5   6641806  POINT (16.89429797664177 52.41856009093589)  POINT (16.89430 52.41856)
6   6641807  POINT (16.89397725037543 52.41832458465358)  POINT (16.89398 52.41832)
7   6641808  POINT (16.89376733989525 52.41815994989702)  POINT (16.89377 52.41816)
8   6641809    POINT (16.89507474142366 52.418304817806)  POINT (16.89507 52.41830)
9   6641810  POINT (16.89417332654704 52.41827195239621)  POINT (16.89417 52.41827)
10  6641811  POINT (16.89432223101175 52.41829509557626)  POINT (16.89432 52.41830)
```

So far I couldn't come up with any reasonable solution.

```
under_curve = addressgpd['geom'] < roadgpd['geom']
```

Analogical to the previous post idea meets with an obvious error:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I have just started programming in Python, so maybe a very different approach to the matter could help. Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Any comment on the answers you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the error you found is already explained by `Mel` in the other answer. To fix it requires some data sorting and densification technique which I will explain in the form of comments within the provided code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt
#from cartopy import crs as ccrs

def xy_to_linecode(x1, y1):
    """
    This creates a WKT linestring code
    """
    line_code = "LINESTRING("
    for ix, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(x1,y1)):
        line_code += str(x) + " " + str(y)
        if ix<len(x1)-1:
            line_code += ", "
        if ix==len(x1)-1:
            line_code += ")"
    return line_code

def xy_to_pntlist(x2, y2):
    """
    This creates a list of WKT point codes
    """
    pnt_head = "POINT("
    all_pnts = []
    for ix, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(x2,y2)):
        pnt_code = pnt_head + str(x) + " " + str(y) + ")"
        all_pnts.append(pnt_code)
    return all_pnts

# Part 1 (make-up data and create geoDataFrames)
# ------
# create data for a line-string
# x1 must be sorted small to large
x1 = [15, 17, 19]
y1 = [52, 51, 54]

d1 = {'col1': [1,],
     'wkt': [
         xy_to_linecode(x1, y1)
         #'LINESTRING (15 52, 17 51, 19 54)',
     ]
    }

# this will be 1 row dataframe
d1f = pd.DataFrame( data=d1 )

# make a geodataframe from d1f (1 LineString)
# `shapely.wkt.loads` converts WKT code to geometry
d1f['geom'] = d1f['wkt'].apply(wkt.loads)
d1f_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d1f, geometry=d1f['geom'])

# create dataframe for points
# x2 must be sorted small to large
x2 = [15.2, 16.0, 16.8, 17.2, 18.0]
y2 = [52, 51, 52, 53, 51]
ids = [101, 102, 103, 104, 105]
d2 = {'id': ids,
     'wkt': xy_to_pntlist(x2, y2)
      #[ 'POINT (15.2 52)',
      #  'POINT (16.0 51)',
      #  'POINT (16.8 52)',
      #  'POINT (17.2 53)',
      #  'POINT (18.0 51)']
    }
d2f = pd.DataFrame( data=d2 )

# make a geodataframe from d2f (several Points)
# `shapely.wkt.loads` converts WKT code to geometry
d2f['geom'] = d2f['wkt'].apply(wkt.loads)
d2f_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(d2f, geometry=d2f['geom'])

# Since (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are intentionally avoided to use
#   assuming working with geodataframes from this steps on ...
#   we must get (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) from the dataframes

# Part 2 (make use of the geoDataFrames)
# ------
# This will get (x1, y1) from d1f_geo, equivalent with (x1, y1) of the original data
xss = []
yss = []
for ea in d1f_geo.geometry.values:
    # expect d1f_geo to have 'LineString' only
    xs, ys = [], []
    if ea.geom_type == 'LineString':
        xs.append(ea.xy[0])
        ys.append(ea.xy[1])
    #print(xs)
    #print(ys)
    xss.append(xs[0])
    yss.append(ys[0])

# intentionally avoid using original (x1, y1)
x1 = xss[0]
y1 = yss[0]

# this will get (x2, y2) from d2f_geo, equivalent with (x2, y2) from the original data
x2s, y2s = [], []
for ea in d2f_geo.geometry.values:
    # expect d2f_geo to cobtain 'POINT' only
    x2s.append(ea.x)
    y2s.append(ea.y)
    #print(ea.x, ea.y)

# intentionally avoid using original (x2, y2)
x2 = x2s
y2 = y2s

# Part 3 (visualization)
# ------
# if Cartopy is used to plot the data, ...
# crs1 = ccrs.PlateCarree()
# fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': crs1})
# fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 5), subplot_kw={'projection': crs1})
# note: axes' labels will not be plotted in this case

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 5))

# plot the single line in `d1f_geo`
kwargs={'linewidth': 1.5, 'linestyles': '--', 'alpha': 0.6}
d1f_geo.plot(color='black', ax=ax, **kwargs)

# xfill will contain all positions in x1 and x2
# that is, x1 or x2 is subset of xfill
xfill = np.sort(np.concatenate([x1, x2]))

# densify y1, y2 data to get equal shape data
y1fill = np.interp(xfill, x1, y1)  # for the lineString's vertices
y2fill = np.interp(xfill, x2, y2)  # for the series of points

# at this state, shapes of the arrays are equal,
# xfill.shape: (8,)
# y1fill.shape: (8,)
# y2fill.shape: (8,)

# the densified `line` data (xfill, y1fill) now have 8 vertices
# the densified `points` data (xfill, y2fill) also have 8 points

# filled color is painted here to visualize how the points/vertices are created
# if you dont need it, change True to False
if True:
    ax.fill_between(xfill, y1fill, y2fill, where=y1fill < y2fill, interpolate=True, color='dodgerblue', alpha=0.1)
    ax.fill_between(xfill, y1fill, y2fill, where=y1fill > y2fill, interpolate=True, color='crimson', alpha=0.1)

# plot numbers at linestring's vertices
# if you dont need this, change True to False
if True:
    id = 0
    for x,y in zip(xfill, y1fill):
        id += 1
        ax.text(x,y,str(id), color='blue')

# point is under or above the line ?
# this only works if `y2fill` and `y1fill` have equal shape
under_curve = None
if y2fill.shape == y1fill.shape:
    under_curve = y2fill < y1fill

# prep list of colors, red (above line), green (below line)
colors = np.array(['green' if b else 'red' for b in under_curve])

# select only original points from (xfill, y2fill) to plot as green and red dots
# the extra (densified) points are plotted in gray
# label: "original" or "densified" are plotted at the points
for x,y,tof,cl in zip(xfill, y2fill, under_curve, colors):
    tf1 = x in x2 and y in y2
    if tf1:
        ax.scatter(x, y, c=cl)  # red or green
        ax.text(x, y, "original", color=cl, alpha=0.65)
    else:
        # the (additional/densified) interpolated point created by `np.interp()`
        # plot them in gray color
        ax.scatter(x, y, c='lightgray', edgecolor='gray', linewidth=0.2)
        ax.text(x, y, "densified", color='gray', alpha=0.75)

plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image: point_under]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because the dataframes do not have the same index values. In this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/whatsnew.html) it explains how to deal when "***Comparison operators raise ValueError when .index are different.***"  To do a comparison operation while ignoring the .index you can try the following:

```py
under_curve = addressgpd['geom'].values < roadgpd['geom'].values
```